# Series getattr with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pass in a tuple of tests to have each one run on a series:

```
deltas = [getattr(test_df.diff().cumsum()[col], test)(0).cumsum() for col, test in zip(test_df.columns, tests)]
```

I can pass in something like `tests = ('lt', 'lt', 'gt')`, but can I pass in a condition along with it? Something like `tests = ('lt(5)', 'lt(2)', 'gt(9)')` (Which doesn't work)?

Comment: have you check eval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution may be to separate the values to apply in a separate tuple. Here is my example (I don't know what is your dataframe, I created a sample):

```
import pandas as pd

tests = ('lt', 'lt', 'gt')
values = (5, 2, 9)

test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': range(10), 'y': [i+1 for i in range(10)],'z': [i*i for i in range(10)]})


deltas = [getattr(test_df.diff().cumsum()[col], test)(value).cumsum() for col, test, value in zip(test_df.columns, tests, values)]
```